# Buildroot seems to not get a response from source urls

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, buildroot

I am attempting to build a Beaglebone image using Buildroot. During the process the build stops and I get this:

```
>>> linux-headers  Downloading
--2019-04-13 11:35:44--  https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v.x/linux-.tar.xz
Resolving cdn.kernel.org (cdn.kernel.org)... 151.101.25.176, 2a04:4e42:6::432
Connecting to cdn.kernel.org (cdn.kernel.org)|151.101.25.176|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-04-13 11:35:44 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2019-04-13 11:35:45--  http://sources.buildroot.net/linux/linux-.tar.xz
Resolving sources.buildroot.net (sources.buildroot.net)... 104.25.210.19, 104.25.211.19, 2606:4700:20::6819:d313, ...
Connecting to sources.buildroot.net (sources.buildroot.net)|104.25.210.19|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-04-13 11:35:45 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2019-04-13 11:35:45--  http://sources.buildroot.net/linux-.tar.xz
Resolving sources.buildroot.net (sources.buildroot.net)... 104.25.210.19, 104.25.211.19, 2606:4700:20::6819:d213, ...
Connecting to sources.buildroot.net (sources.buildroot.net)|104.25.210.19|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-04-13 11:35:45 ERROR 404: Not Found.

package/pkg-generic.mk:143: recipe for target '/home/bdn/buildroot-2019.02.1/output/build/linux-headers/.stamp_downloaded' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/bdn/buildroot-2019.02.1/output/build/linux-headers/.stamp_downloaded] Error 1
Makefile:84: recipe for target '_all' failed
make: *** [_all] Error 2
```

I do not know how to fix/update these. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

An information of version should miss somewhere, you're trying to download at https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v.x/

Look here https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/, it should be /v4.x, /v5.x or whatever version you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Is this our upstream beaglebone_defconfig or did you change anything? With the upstream defconfig, kernel headers are configured to use the kernel sources fetched from git.ti.com, but the above looks like Buildroot tries to download a tarball of the mainline kernel headers (but the version fields are empty).

Checking here with 2019.02.1:

```
make beaglebone_defconfig && make linux-headers
..
>>> linux-headers 4796173fc58688055a99a1cef19a839174067220 Downloading
Fetching all references
remote: Counting objects: 2298744
```

Comment: Because I am using a TI-Linux kernel on my Beaglebone, TI provides a script in the tools folder to upgrade the kernel to with the preempt_rt patch, which was my intended goal with building the TI-Linux source then patching with the preempt_rt patch.

Comment: I am having this issue as well. I'm using `LINUX_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR` to provide a custom kernel tree with the rt patches already applied to it. However `make source` or `make legal-info` causes `>>> linux-headers  Downloading` to fail exactly as shown.